# i'm developing a web server that get payloads from a github webhook in python

Tags: python, github, github-api, slack-api, github-webhook

i'm developing a web server in python that get payloads from a github webhook for specific events (push, new commits, pull requset...) how can i distenguise between thoese events throw gson?
i've looked in the payload but fond nothing..:/
but in the other hand - i have a code that creates a handler for push event :

@webhook.hook()        # Defines a handler for the 'push' event
def on_push(data):
print("Got push with: {0}".format(data))

so is there a built in "event detector" in the webhook library?
found nothing online

EDIT     : found this :"The type of activity is specified in the action property of the payload object. "
BUT there is no keyword action in the payload i got
and the type of event i triggered in github is a commit
but all i got in payload says : 'modified': ['README.md'] 'message': 'Update README.md
nothing straight forward

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to parse the event type in the `action` property or in the `X-GitHub-Event` header value as noted in [this documentation](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/event-payloads/#webhook-payload-object-common-properties)

If you're willing to use TypeScript instead, there's a great library for handling this parsing automatically called [Probot](https://github.com/probot/probot).

Alternatively, if you want to stick to Python, there's this library which is similar: https://github.com/bradshjg/flask-githubapp

Comment: thank you, i used the request.headers['X-GitHub-Event']

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Please see "How does accepting an answer work?": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work